# how creates a frame one time and use it everywhere and everytime?

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, singleton, frame

In my program there are 10 connections in connectionList. For each connection I create my frames again. It means I create the same frame for 10 times. I want to create it only 1 time and use it for 10 times,not create for each connection. I can not design it. I sent my part of code about create frame. Could you make only one example among them for me. Should I use ***Singleton Pattern***? What is the solution way and how should make it? Because in real program I have 25 frames like that. If you make one of these I can do other 24 frames.
Best Regards

**Main Class**

```
for (String wn : connectionList) {
            if (!workSpacesNames.contains(wn)) {
                try {
                    DWorkspace workSpace = new DWorkspace(wn, DMainFrame.this);

                    workSpaces.add(workSpace);

                    tabbedPane.addTab(workSpace.getTitle(), workSpace.getHolderPanel());

                    workSpace.getDockingManager().setShowWorkspace(showWorkspaceArea);

                    workSpace.getDockingManager().beginLoadLayoutData();

                    if (UserAuthorization.getUserAuth().isAuthorized(CommandAuthType.CANCELEDORDERS_WINDOW)) {
                        workSpace.getDockingManager().addFrame(DFrameFactory.createClosedOrderTable(
                                workSpace, canceledOrderSound, DockContext.STATE_HIDDEN));
                    }
                    if (UserAuthorization.getUserAuth().isAuthorized(CommandAuthType.CANCELEDSTRATEGIES_WINDOW)) {
                        workSpace.getDockingManager().addFrame(DFrameFactory.createClosedStrategyTable(
                                workSpace, canceledStrategySound, DockContext.STATE_HIDDEN));
                    }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                log.trace("exception in DMainFrame", ex);
            }
                    }
                    }
```

**Create Frames Class**

```
    public class DFrameFactory {

    private DFrameFactory() {
    }

 public static DockableFrame createClosedOrderTable(DWorkspace workspace,JCheckBoxMenuItem canceledOrderSound, int context) {
        DockableFrame frame = new DockableFrame("closedorders");
        frame.setTitle(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.neyre.dallar.frame.framefactory.closedorders.title"));
        frame.setTabTitle(
                ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.neyre.dallar.frame.framefactory.closedorders.tabtitle"));
        frame.setSideTitle(ELanguage.getString(
                "(LANG)org.neyre.dallar.frame.framefactory.closedorders.sidetitle"));
        frame.getContext().setInitMode(context);
        frame.getContext().setInitSide(DockContext.DOCK_SIDE_SOUTH);
        frame.getContext().setInitIndex(1);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new DFClosedOrderTable(workspace, canceledOrderSound));

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 300));
        frame.setDockedWidth(750);
        frame.setFrameIcon(EIcons.getSmallIcon(EIcons.ERROR));
        return frame;
    }

     public static DockableFrame createClosedStrategyTable(DWorkspace workspace,JCheckBoxMenuItem canceledStrategySound, int context) {
        DockableFrame frame = new DockableFrame("closedstrategies");
        frame.setTitle(ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.neyre.dallar.frame.framefactory.closedstrategies.title"));
        frame.setTabTitle(
                ELanguage.getString("(LANG)org.neyre.dallar.frame.framefactory.closedstrategies.tabtitle"));
        frame.setSideTitle(ELanguage.getString(
                "(LANG)org.neyre.dallar.frame.framefactory.closedstrategies.sidetitle"));
        frame.getContext().setInitMode(context);
        frame.getContext().setInitSide(DockContext.DOCK_SIDE_SOUTH);
        frame.getContext().setInitIndex(1);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new DFClosedStrategyTable(workspace, canceledStrategySound));

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 300));
        frame.setDockedWidth(750);
        frame.setFrameIcon(EIcons.getSmallIcon(EIcons.ERROR));
        return frame;
    }

  }
```

Comment: What is a `DockableFrame`? Never mind.. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) - that will explain it.

Comment: DockableFrame is an abstract class and it extends JComponent. Do you want to see DockableFrame class's code?

Comment: *"Do you want to see.."* For better help sooner.. Please read both documents before making any edits.

Comment: What is the wrong Mr. Andrew Thompson?

Comment: Başka yolu yok mu diyorsun Reşit Usta ?

Comment: *"Başka yolu yok mu diyorsun Reşit Usta ?"* Please use English. It is a requirement of this site, besides just making sense. *"What is the wrong Mr. Andrew Thompson?"* ..but I don't understand what you're asking, even in English. Can you explain what you mean? More words would be better than less at times like these.

Comment: I mean is my question not clear? Is my question incomprehensible ? If there is a complexity I wanna explain it. What is the incomplete part of my question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code above if the user can view only one connection properties at a time, then it is fine to create a singleton instance of the frame. But if the user can simultaneously view more than one connections you have to create more than one frame.

But creation of frames can follow different patterns

- Singleton if viewing only one frame
- Lazy initialization of frame
- creating a pool of frames and reusing it.

Again to use which approach would be based on the use case and UX